# how to add a circled image Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

as I am new to Reactjs I want to add an image I know I can use  but I don't know how to make it circled if someone can help me with an example for using it.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow Khaled! It's not really clear what you are asking, so it will be hard for us to help you. Please include the code you have written so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use css with a [border-radius](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_rounded_images.asp).

```
<img src='url' style={{ borderRadius: '50%'}} />
```